# JavaScript works when setTimeout() is used, but it isn't working when document.eventListener('DOMContentLoaded', x) is used on a WordPress page. Why?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, event-handling, settimeout, addeventlistener

I have a few lines of JavaScript code that pick up heading texts from separate sections and place them into their respective input fields. They are also executed on single pages using `wp_enqueue_script`.

It works absolutely fine when `setTimeout()` is used:

```
function passengerElevator() {
  var getProductName = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="6657316"]');
    getProductName.forEach(function(item) {
      var productName = item.querySelector('.lift');
      var inputArea = item.querySelector('input[name=product]');
      inputArea.value = productName.innerText;
  });
  var getProductName = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="e9c06d5"]');
    getProductName.forEach(function(item) {
      var productName = item.querySelector('.lift');
      var inputArea = item.querySelector('input[name=product]');
      inputArea.value = productName.innerText;
  });
setTimeout(function() { passengerElevator() },3000);
```

However, there is problem of page size (some pages have more than 10 input fields) and I don't want to set an astronomically high `ms` to delay the script. So I decided to fire it on `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", passengerElevator);
function passengerElevator() {
  var getProductName = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="6657316"]');
    getProductName.forEach(function(item) {
      var productName = item.querySelector('.lift'); // heading text (ex:Panoramic Lift)
      var inputArea = item.querySelector('input[name=product]');
      inputArea.value = productName.innerText; //ouput here
  });
  var getProductName = document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="e9c06d5"]');
    getProductName.forEach(function(item) {
      var productName = item.querySelector('.lift'); // Heading text (ex:Home Lift)
      var inputArea = item.querySelector('input[name=product]');
      inputArea.value = productName.innerText; // Output here
  });
}
```

As you may have already guessed, it is not working. Is my code too messy to be executed faster or is there any other problem I am missing?

<sub>I know similar questions have been asked previously, however, no existing answer I found was able to help me.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you try to loop through elements that are still not loaded. Perhaps they are being appended to the page via Ajax, so `DOMContentLoaded` can't help there.

You can create your own check for those elements using `setInterval`, so use something like this:

```js
let dataIdCheck = setInterval(() => {
    if (document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="6657316"]').length > 0 && document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="e9c06d5"]').length > 0) {
        clearInterval(dataIdCheck);

        // your code here
    }
}, 500);
```

This code will run every 500 milliseconds and check if those two elements exists, using `.length`. Once they do exists, we stop the interval and run the code.

I also suggest to do `console.log('in')` to check that our interval stop running once the elements are found.

Comment: it seems like you are right about premature loop although the script is executed in the `footer`.  thank you for your answer. glad to know that stackoverflow isn't only for experts.

Comment: @junior_dev Even if the scrip is executed in the footer it doesn't mean it will run after all elements are loaded, if they are loaded via XHR they will always be available after DOM is loaded. Your question diden't say anything about XHR elements but from your problem I assumed its the case. If this question solved your problem consider accepting it as the answer.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. thanks anyways

Comment: @junior_dev Have you put the `console.log` inside the `if` block?, have you seen it in the browser DevTools?. Consider updating your question with the new code that you tested, it will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: it worked. thanks man, I appreciate it. Earlier there was a typo in my code. One last question? Does it have any performance issues?

Comment: @junior_dev Some for sure but nothing major, your elements are probably loaded after a few seconds so `setInterval` will only runa a few times until it stopes, the `if` condition is not that resource heavy. Overall the performance hit will be next to zero.